# random array of 1-20 using only one function Rand100()

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have to get an array of no 1-20 without repeatition arranged in random order. All I can use is a function Rand100() which gives a random number between 1-100? Please answer in javascript if possible.

Comment: Unless Rand100 itself guarantees no repetition, then there's no way to do this without running the risk of "retries" whenever it does repeat itself.  Without knowing more about how you ended up with this strange problem, the only code I can give you is `for(var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) { array[i] = Rand100() / 5; }`

Comment: As many solutions as one can quote here are appreciated as I am not good at algorithm and I would love to see the logic of every solution.
RULES:
1. you can not use any other function to generate a random number. 
2. you have to keep the run time constant.

Comment: @Ixrec Please see the answers. Both solutions are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sampleArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
var arrayTemp = [];
for (var i = 20;i>=0;i--){
   var temp = Rand100()%i;
   arrayTemp.push(sampleArray[temp]);
   sampleArray.splice(temp,1);
};
console.log(arrayTemp);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should give you a starting point.  I used Math.random instead of Rand100 - but they should yield similar results.
array_to_randomize is the array containing the elements you want to randomize.
random contains the results of the randomization.

```
    /* Array to Randomize */
var array_to_randomize = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"]
/* Results */
var random = [];

var j = 0, 
        i = array_to_randomize.length;

while (i > 0){
    j = Math.random() * array_to_randomize.length;
    random.push(array_to_randomize.splice(j,1))
    i = array_to_randomize.length;

}

random.forEach(function(value,index){console.log("index: " +  index + " value: " + value)})
```