# Randomize figure class images

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to randomize/shuffle images on this html code?

```html
<div id="projects" class="clearfix">

<!-- ENSAIO PESSOAL -->
<figure class="mix portfolio-item pessoal">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/EnsaioPessoal/1_preview.jpg" data-order="1" alt="Galeria">
    <a href="img/portfolio/EnsaioPessoal/1.jpg" title="Foto de ensaio pessoal" rel="portfolio" class="fancybox">
        <span class="plus"></span>
    </a>
    <figcaption class="mask">
        <h3>Ensaio pessoal</h3>
        <span>Algum comentário</span>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<!-- ENSAIO PESSOAL -->
<figure class="mix portfolio-item pessoal">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/EnsaioPessoal/1_preview.jpg" data-order="1" alt="Galeria">
    <a href="img/portfolio/EnsaioPessoal/1.jpg" title="Foto de ensaio pessoal" rel="portfolio" class="fancybox">
        <span class="plus"></span>
    </a>
    <figcaption class="mask">
        <h3>Ensaio pessoal</h3>
        <span>Algum comentário</span>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<!-- ENSAIO PESSOAL -->
<figure class="mix portfolio-item pessoal">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/EnsaioPessoal/2_preview.jpg" data-order="2" alt="Galeria">
    <a href="img/portfolio/EnsaioPessoal/2.jpg" title="Foto de ensaio pessoal" rel="portfolio" class="fancybox">
        <span class="plus"></span>
    </a>
    <figcaption class="mask">
        <h3>Ensaio pessoal</h3>
        <span>Algum comentário</span>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<!-- ENSAIO PESSOAL -->
<figure class="mix portfolio-item pessoal">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/EnsaioPessoal/3_preview.jpg" data-order="3" alt="Galeria">
    <a href="img/portfolio/EnsaioPessoal/3.jpg" title="Foto de ensaio pessoal" rel="portfolio" class="fancybox">
        <span class="plus"></span>
    </a>
    <figcaption class="mask">
        <h3>Ensaio pessoal</h3>
        <span>Algum comentário</span>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

</div>
```

Like this:

(IMAGE 1) (IMAGE 2) (IMAGE 3)

When I refresh the page:
(IMAGE 3) (IMAGE 2) (IMAGE 1)

again:
(IMAGE 2) (IMAGE 3) (IMAGE 1)

How can I do it? I tried so many things, and nothing! I can't do it alone

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: Do you want to shuffle the `<figure>` elements that contain the `<img>` elements, or just the images themselves?

Comment: Only shuffle images, after refreshing the page!

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143234/random-array-of-1-20-using-only-one-function-rand100

Comment: This does not match my code I believe, and about shuffle the figure elements, there's a example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a new array of images with random ordering, then replace the `#projects` container old html with said new array of images.

```
//Get references to the container, images, and number of images
let $container = $("#projects")
let $images = $(".mix.portfolio-item.pessoal")
let numImages =$images.length

//Create a new array of images by randomly assigning indexes from 0--numImages
//and replacing the containers html with this new array
let newOrderOfImages = []
$images.each((index, img) => {
    let newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numImages)

    //Keep creating random indexes until an empty one is found
    while(newOrderOfImages[newIndex] !== undefined) {
        newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numImages)
    }

    newOrderOfImages[newIndex] = img
})

$container.html(newOrderOfImages)
```

Comment: I got problems with this code, btw, thanks for your reply. 

I'm still using MixItUp plugin, there's a way to insert it on this plugin? I still using this code, but still not working to update these images

@edit: I'm getting problems to insert code here, so, here you go pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/mzFzedEV

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin you're using but after looking at its docs, You need to move the `data-order` from the `img` elements and put it on its container `figure` elements. And you can remove the previous code i provided you.